# how to save a jquery slider's selected value

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

Does any one know how I can save a slider's value in the database? I would like to save the slider's position when the user stops sliding. I have no problem get the value
on the client side but I need to save the selected slider value in the database as well.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make this work but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it.
I created a HiddenField and assign the slider's ui.value by using the syntax below:
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_sliders_SliderStoppedValue").val(SliderStoppedValue);